# Executing Javascript on Selenium/PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm using `PhantomJS` via Selenium Webdriver in Python and I'm trying to execute a piece of JavaScript on the page in hopes of returning a piece of data:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS("phantomjs.cmd") # or add to your PATH
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768) # optional
driver.get('http://google.com') # EXAMPLE, not actual URL

driver.save_screenshot('screen.png') # save a screenshot to disk
jsres = driver.execute('$("#list").DataTable().data()')
print(jsres)
```

However when run, it reports `KeyError`. I was unable to find much documentation on the commands available, so I'm a bit stuck here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method created for executing javascript is called [`execute_script()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script), not `execute()`:

```
driver.execute_script('return $("#list").DataTable().data();')
```

FYI, `execute()` is used internally for sending webdriver commands.

Note that if you want something returned by javascript code, you need to use `return`.

Also note that this can throw `Can't find variable: $` error message. In this case, locate the element with `selenium` and pass it into the script:

```
# explicitly wait for the element to become present
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "list")))

# pass the found element into the script
jsres = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].DataTable().data();', element)
print(jsres)
```